# Excel VBA Macro to make highlighted cells be the same as the next non-highlighted cell above it

Tags: vba, excel

This sounds complicated, but this is what I have to make a macro of for work. Listed below is a sample of the list of item codes that I have: (`'h' stands for highlighted cell`)

> M101
>
> S644 (h)
>
> S753 (h)
>
> M102
>
> S531 (h)  etc....

I want to make the macro to give this end result using any method:

> M101
>
> M101 (h)
>
> M101 (h)
>
> M102
>
> M102 (h)
>
> etc....

Can someone link me a sample VBA macro that I can use to get this process done? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that 'M101' for example is not a cell but rather a value in a column.
Some googling of what my pseudocode solution below will set you on the right track if I have assumed correctly...

```
for (column):  
if (currentCell is highlighted) then  
currentCell.value = currentCell.one_up.value
```